# How to find an FSRef from a directory ID and a volume number?

Tags: macos, filesystems, macos-carbon

Given an FSRef of a directory, one can use `FSGetCatalogInfo` to find the volume reference number and the directory ID.  Together, these two numbers should be enough to identify the directory.  One way to go the other direction would be use `FSMakeFSSpec( vRefNum, dirID, "\p", &fileSpec )` and then `FSpMakeFSRef( &fileSpec, &dirRef )`.  However, `FSMakeFSSpec` and `FSpMakeFSRef` are deprecated.  I'm wondering whether there is a way to go from vRefNum and dirID to FSRef using functions that are not deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used it, but it seems `FSResolveNodeID` may do what you want. Apple pretty much scrubbed its ADC site clean of everything Carbon so I can't find a link to it. But you can look it up in `Files.h`. Also, it's only available in 10.5 or later.

Comment: You're right, it's undocumented except for header comments.  Too bad it requires 10.5, since `FSMakeFSSpec` was deprecated in 10.4.

Comment: thanks!  It took hours of groveling through apple's crap documentation and discontinued APIs to find this.